# SWIFT: Data model for "Like" button functionality in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I'm creating a playlist app (Mock-Up Below) using Swift and Parse. Each user has the ability add a song (or multiple songs) to the TableView and "Like" or "Dislike" (toggle style) as many songs as they like, including their own. This functionality is very similar to the Instagram "Like" button behaviour.

I'm having a bit of trouble conceptualizing the data model. As shown below, I have a User table and a Playlist table (with all of the added songs):

[image]

User Table:
[image]
Playlist Table:
[image]

I'm having trouble with the next step, which is storing the "Like" data for each user and each song.

**UPDATED:** I've added a column in the 'PlaylistData' table in Parse called "userVotes". As you can see, I'm appending all of the data into an array called 'voters'. For some reason, I'm getting a fatal run time error - 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class MusicPlaylistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var usernames = [String]()
var songs = [String]()
var voters = [String]()

var numVotes = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    let query = PFQuery(className:"PlaylistData")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                self.usernames.removeAll()
                self.songs.removeAll()
                self.voters.removeAll()

                for object in objects {

                    let username = object["username"] as? String
                    self.usernames.append(username!)

                    let track = object["song"] as? String
                    self.songs.append(track!)

                    self.voters = object["userVotes"] as! [String]
                    print(self.voters)
                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }


}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return usernames.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTrack", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TrackTableViewCell

    cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row]
    cell.votes.text = "\(numVotes)"

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



}


}
```

I've also created a TableViewCell swift file for the prototype cell:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class TrackTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var numVotes = 0

@IBOutlet weak var songTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var votes: UILabel!

@IBAction func voteButton(sender: UIButton) {

    self.numVotes = self.numVotes + 1
    self.votes.text = "\(self.numVotes)"


}
}
```

At this point, all it does is when the heart is clicked, it increases the vote count by 1 on screen (the user can do this as many times as possible, no data is stored in the database). What I need help with is the best way to implement table(s) which allow me to keep track of which users have voted for each song (or not).  I know I need a TRUE / FALSE column somewhere, but I can't seem to figure out how to model it.  Any suggestions or links to SWIFT tutorials would be greatly appreciated. A simple explanation on what tables to create (or what columns to add to existing tables) would help the best. Thanks!

Comment: Introduce an array type column in your table `playListData`. Populate it with  objectIds of all the users who "heart" them. Then while displaying, check if that array contains objectId of your current user, if it does, make the heart red. Show count of that array as total likes at bottom

Comment: also if some user likes it first and then dislikes it, you can update that PFObject and save it.

Comment: If you have any other questions or if you are still confused about this approach, feel free to ask.

Comment: @NSNoob, thanks for your help...your solution makes complete sense.  I've included an update in my original post.  For some reason, I'm getting a fatal runtime error when I try to append the array column in the table into the array I added into the view controller.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `let userVoters = object["userVotes"] as? String`  here you have array of userVoters. On next line, you are appending this array into your array named self.voters when you have already declared it as array of strings, not array of arrays. Replace those both lines with this lines:

`self.voters = object["userVotes"] as? String`

Comment: @NSNoob, I made the change and got the error "Cannot assign a value of type String to a value of type [String]".

Comment: I work with obj-c so my working knowledge of swift is limited. Sorry about that. Get ride of `as ? string`. Only `self.voters = object["userVotes" ]` That ought to do the trick. If it works, let me know so that i can post this as an answer

Comment: @NSNoob, it ended up being: self.voters = object["userVotes"] as! [String]. It runs with this code, but the voters array ends up being ["ID1", "ID2, "ID3"...], vs. [["ID1", "ID2", "ID3"], ["ID4", "ID5", "ID6"], ["ID7", "ID8", "ID9"]...].

Comment: The first array in this array is votes of your first playList. Second Array is votes of your second playList. You are not putting any constraints on query so you are getting all playList objects. As a result you are getting votes for all of them appended in your array.

Comment: You should make a data model for your playList Type. Populate it with the PFObject of PlaylistType you retrieve. And then Keep all those model objects in your array. Populate each cell with each of that data model.